# error when add product barcode to Odoo excel report

Tags: python, odoo

trying to add product barcode to Odoo excel report but not successful as it is shown below in this line:

*aml.product_id.barcode AS product_barcode*

could you please help where's the wrong section in the code?

```
    def _sql_get_line_for_report(self, type_l, report_object=None):
        self.env['account.move.line'].check_access_rights('read')
        query = """SELECT
                    raml.report_object_id AS report_object_id,
                    raml.view_type AS view_type,
                    CASE
                        WHEN %s = 'account' THEN acc.code
                        WHEN %s = 'journal' THEN acj.code
                        WHEN %s = 'analytic' THEN an_acc.code
                        ELSE rep.ref
                    END AS code,
                    CASE
                        WHEN %s = 'account' THEN acc.name
                        WHEN %s = 'journal' THEN acj.name
                        WHEN %s = 'analytic' THEN an_acc.name
                        ELSE rep.name
                    END AS name,
                    acj.code AS j_code,
                    ml.name AS move_name,
                    aml.ref AS displayed_ref,
                    aml.quantity AS product_qty,
                    aml.product_id.barcode AS product_barcode,
                    CASE
                        WHEN raml.full_reconcile_id IS NOT NULL THEN (CASE WHEN raml.reconciled = TRUE THEN afr.name ELSE '*' END)
                        ELSE ''
                    END AS matching_number
                FROM
                    account_report_standard_ledger_line raml
                    LEFT JOIN account_account acc ON (acc.id = raml.account_id)
                    LEFT JOIN account_journal acj ON (acj.id = raml.journal_id)
                    LEFT JOIN res_partner rep ON (rep.id = raml.partner_id)
                    LEFT JOIN account_move ml ON (ml.id = raml.move_id)
                    LEFT JOIN account_move_line aml ON (aml.id = raml.move_line_id)
                WHERE
                    raml.report_id = %s
                    AND (%s OR raml.report_object_id = %s)
                    AND raml.line_type IN %s
                ORDER BY
                    raml.id
                """
        params = [
            self.report_type, self.report_type, self.report_type, self.report_type, self.report_type, self.report_type,
            self.report_id.id,
            True if report_object is None else False,
            report_object,
            type_l
        ]

        self.env.cr.execute(query, tuple(params))
        return self.env.cr.dictfetchall()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We simply can not use two level field values inside a query. First, we need to add LEFT JOIN for the product table and then access 'barcode' value. For example,

LEFT JOIN:

```
LEFT JOIN product_product variant ON (variant.id = aml.product_id)
```

Access value:

```
variant.barcode AS product_barcode,
```

Comment: thank you very much, appraciated.